# kdb+ conditional insert: only insert when column value doesn't exist

Tags: insert-update, kdb

What is the best way to insert a row into a table, only if a column of that row doesn't exist in the table.

E.g.:

```
q)table:([] col1:(); col2:(); col3:());
q)`table insert (1;2;3);
q)conditionalInsert:{if[first where table.col1=x(0)~0N;`table insert x]};
```

Now when doing the following:

```
q)conditionalInsert[(1;2;3)];
q)conditionalInsert[(7;8;9)];
```

The result yields:

```
q)table
col1 col2 col3
--------------
1    2    3
7    8    9
```

This can probably be accomplished more easily. My question: **what is the easiest/best way?**

To be clear: the column may be a non-keyed one.

Or in other words: **Table is either keyed or non keyed and target column is not a key (or part of the compound key columns)**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First thing is to have proper attributes (sort,group) on the target column which will make function faster.

Now there are 2 scenarios I can think of:

a)  **Table is keyed and target column is keyed column :**  In this case normal insert will work in way like your conditional insert.

b) **Table is either keyed or non keyed and target column is not a key (or part of the compound key columns) :**

```
         q)conditionalInsert: {if[not x[0] in table.col1;`table insert x]}
```

Its better to use 'exec' in place of  'table.col1' as dot notation doesn't work for keyed table:

```
         q)conditionalInsert: {if[not x[0] in exec col1 from table;`table insert x]}
```

Comment: Scenario b indeed. I have updated my question. Is there no shorter/easier way to do it than by creating the function?

Comment: You are asking if KDB provides any builtin function to do this , I don't think so. Even if there is , it will do the same thing at the back end or might temporarily  make the column as primary key and  do insert.

Comment: Maybe you are right. I'll keep it open a bit longer to see if any other responses come up.

Answer (score 3):

Use a keyed table?

```
q)table  
col1| col2 col3  
----| ---------  
1   | 2    3  
q)`table insert (1;2;4)  
'insert  
q)`table insert (2;2;4)  
,1  
q)table  
col1| col2 col3  
----| ---------  
1   | 2    3  
2   | 2    4
```

you can always use protected evaluation to silent the error.

```
q).[insert;(`table;(1;2;4));{`already_there}]  
`already_there  
q).[insert;(`table;(3;2;4));{`already_there}]  
,2  
q)table  
col1| col2 col3  
----| ---------  
1   | 2    3  
2   | 2    4  
3   | 2    4
```

Comment: This is indeed the best answer for a keyed column but I also would like to find a clean solution for a non-keyed one.